# CP Error 1001 Out of memory

Tags: constraint-programming

I have an optimization project coded in IBM ILOG optimization studio using CP. When the size of the input data grows, I am getting out of memory errors etc. What can I do to make CP use disk and reduce the memory usage of CP?

Comment: Very classical situation when dealing with combinatorial optimization.. it depends of course on the problem at hand and specially on your encoding. If you detail more your problem we can probably help you to improve your modelling